# matlab colormap in python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I need the orignal image once again but its returning greyscale
my teacher said do colormap at the beginning and said that it happens in matlab. so i want to do similar task in python too
Here is my code have a look
please help

ENCRYPTION:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
x = Image.open('1.jpg', 'r')
x = x.convert('L')

y = np.asarray(x.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((x.size[1], x.size[0]))#changed image to matrix getdata for matrix value                                                              # dtype is int type reshape used to break  1d array into 2d array
y = np.asarray(y, dtype=np.uint8)#if values still in range 0-255!
#print(y)
z = y
w = Image.fromarray(y, mode='L')
w.save('grey_scale.bmp')
for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(len(z[i])):
        a = z[i][j]
        p = int(bin(a)[2:])
        p = '%08d' % p
        p = p[::-1]
        z[i][j] = int(p, 2)
#print(z)

C = Image.fromarray(z)
C.save('decryption.bmp')
print("DONE")
```

DECRYPTION:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
x = Image.open('decryption.bmp', 'r')

y = np.asarray(x.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((x.size[1], x.size[0]))#changed image to matrix getdata for matrix value
#print(y)                                                             # dtype is int type reshape used to break  1d array into 2d array
y = np.asarray(y, dtype=np.uint8)#if values still in range 0-255!
#print(y)
z = y
for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(len(z[i])):
        a = z[i][j]
        p = int(bin(a)[2:])
        p = '%08d' % p
        p = p[::-1]
        z[i][j] = int(p, 2)
#print(z)

C = Image.fromarray(z)
C.save('Final.bmp')
print("DONE")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your looking for here. Your line x = x.convert('L') will convert your image to greyscale.  The colour information is lost and no amount of processing will get it back.  Unless you're asking about Tone mapping?

Comment: can you modify the given code above so that it will take input an RGB image and then give output as rgb image but do the processing in greyscale

Answer (score 0):

I think(?) what you're looking for is a [Colour Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mapping) function like:

```
def create_colourmap(colour, grey):
    c_map = numpy.zeros((256,4), dtype=numpy.float64)
    for i in range(colour.shape[0]):
        for j in range(colour.shape[1]):
            tone = grey[i,j]
            c_map[tone,3] +=1
            count = c_map[tone, 3]
            c_map[tone,:3]  = (c_map[tone,:3] * (count-1)  + colour[i,j])/count
    return c_map.astype(numpy.uint8)[:,:3]
```

Which would give you ONE colour value for each Greyscale value (or Tone).

Your 'bit reversal' procedure could be simplified by another function:

```
def reverse_bits(arr):
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            arr[i][j] = int('{0:08b}'.format(arr[i][j])[::-1], 2)
    return arr
```

Putting this all together, your encrypt function would be:

```
def encrypt(infile, outfile):

    with Image.open(infile, 'r') as colour_img:
        colour_arr = numpy.array(colour_img)
        grey_img = colour_img.convert('L')

    grey_arr = numpy.array(grey_img)
    c_map = create_colourmap(colour_arr, grey_arr)

    with Image.fromarray(c_map) as cmap_img:
        cmap_img.save(outfile[:-4]+'_cmap.bmp')

    grey_arr = reverse_bits(grey_arr)

    with Image.fromarray(grey_arr) as c:
        c.save(outfile)
    print("Encryption DONE")
```

And your decrypt function:

```
def decrypt(infile, outfile):
    with Image.open(infile, 'r') as x:
        y = numpy.array(x)
    y = reverse_bits(y)

    colour_arr = numpy.zeros((y.shape[0], y.shape[1], 3), dtype=numpy.uint8)

    with Image.open(infile[:-4]+'_cmap.bmp') as cmap_img:
        cmap = numpy.array(cmap_img)

    for i in range(256):
        colour_arr[y==i] = cmap[i]
    
    with Image.fromarray(colour_arr) as c:
        c.save(outfile)
    print("Decryption DONE")
```

You'll notice that the Colour Mapping will not completely restore the image colour, but will give the image some hue.  I don't know what your assignment is about, but you may want to send the Colour Map along with the encrypted image, or give them another image with similar colouring.

I hope this helps you, but you will need to lean how this works, and comment where necessary to explain whats going on.

Good luck!